# How to write a loop withcondition in jquery template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side, jquery-templates

Consider following logic as requirement:

```
var count=4;

for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
{
  /* create a table row <tr></tr> */
}
```

Now if I where try do the same thing with my jquery template where in I want to try to do something as below:

```
<script id="MyTemplate" type="text/html">
        <table id="MyTable" class="Grid">            
            <tbody>
               {{each count}}
                <tr>
                  <td>${Name}</td>
                <tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
</script>
```

where in the data I am trying to bind to template is :

```
var count=4;
var Name=["Peter","Michael","John","Thomas","James","Joseph","Mary","Simon"];
```

And the ouput I want my template to generate is:

```
<table id="MyTable" class="Grid">            
            <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Peter</td>
                    <td>Michael</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Thomas</td>
                  <tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>James</td>
                    <td>Joseph</td>
                    <td>Mary</td>
                    <td>Simon</td>
                  <tr>

           </tbody>
       </table>
```

I have already tried:

```
<script id="TestTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    Day:<br/>
    <table>
     <tbody>
        {{for(i=1;i<=${count};i++)}}
        <tr></tr>
        {{/for }}
     </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

But by doing the above implementation in the templates, the tmpl library throws "Template command not found" error.

Can anyone suggestion solution to do this?

Comment: @Chase i already tried that but I get jQuery.tmpl.tag is null error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
{{each(i) Name}}
    {{if i < count}}
        <tr></tr>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```